# Windows 10 Bash - how to automatically cd into a directory after launching

Tags: bash, windows-10, cd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way for Bash to automatically change the directory after it is launched?

At present I have to type `cd /mnt/c`... each time I open Bash.

Comment: Does putting a `cd` command into your `.bashrc` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your `cd /mnt/c` command (on a new line) at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file.